# Mobile to Raspberry PI audio streaming

Tags: audio, linux, streaming, wolfson-audio-card

I have trying to use the Raspberry PI + Wolfson to be an audio decoder and player. It would be the receiver for control/audio data for a specialized sound system. The PI would receive TCP packets from a mobile device and translate that and send it to the sound system's controller. The PI receives through Wifi and is connected to the sound system controller through Ethernet cable. If a command request to start an audio broadcast, the PI would start listening for RTP packets from the device and convert them to audio to be played through the Wolfson card.

I have looked at OpenOB and that is the closest thing I could find to my intended implementation. What libraries would I need to use considering the transmitting devices are to be smartphones? So as cross-platform as possible would be best. Any other ideas and advice are welcome. Sorry that I could not be as specific as possible as.

Comment: No cross polatform availble.. thanks to tough competition and trade makrks. iphone you can use airplay, and android you can use something new they just made. Winows.. behind as usuall and have nothing. But look into Plex (Premium) and PLex server. They have interesting solutions.

Comment: I used XBMC based distros (Raspbmc, XBian) once, they were compatible with WiFi streaming formats such as AirPlay.

Answer (score 1):

Excluding Windows, where I haven't found a solution yet, you can use AirPlay protocol. Will work with iOS/Mac OS devices, some Android apps, Linux with PulseAudio-RAOP2 (needs manual compilation but that's the only "tweak" needed). On the RPi you just have to install ShairPort and it should work. Auto-discovery on devices with the help of ZeroConf and no other configuration needed.

About the connection between the RPi and your sound system, I don't know how it works.